# What Benefit Generics provide over legacy Code:

Tags: java, generics

**i have read on docs.oracle site that  The following code snippet without generics requires casting:**

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("hello");
String s = (String) list.get(0);
```

but if i write code with Generics then it is still prone to Error:

```
List<Object>= new List<Object>;
list.add("hello");
String s=(String)list.get(0);
```

what is then the real use of generics....:( thnx in advance..

Comment: `List<String>` would prevent you from adding non-`String` items. Tada!

Answer (score 4):

```
List<Object>= new List<Object>;
list.add("hello");
String s=(String)list.get(0);
```

Should be

```
List<String>= new ArrayList<String>();    // this is now a list of String, not a list of object
     ^^^^^^                 ^^^^^^
list.add("hello");
String s=list.get(0);    // no casting needed
         ^
```

**You parameterize by the type you want.** Your example are 2 ways to do the same thing, since you parameterize by the most basic class.

The advantage of generics is that you can write classes that are more specific to one class, `String` here. This gives you better type safety to catch bugs early during compilation. This prevents issues arising from the casting approach.

Comment: You have a typo here `new List<String>;`

Comment: okay i get it...this means that i can  Add specific data type to a container object. And compiler Checks for it at compile time...fine

Answer (score 3):

Using generics makes your code Type Safe. You can prevent `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you want to store a list of names(string)

```
List listNames = new ArrayList();
listNames.add("Durgesh");//ok
```

But I could also add an integer to it

```
listNames.add(5000);//storing int instead of string
```

Now do this

```
String name2=listNames.get(1);//throws exception{int->string}
```

Without generics you could add invalid types to collection which could break your code.

---

With **generics** you could solve the problem

```
List<String> listNames = new ArrayList();
listNames.add("Durgesh");
listNames.add(3000);//would through error at compile time
```

So,generics provides **typesafety**

---

With `List<Object>` you intend to add any kind of Object.Due to Object parameter,it would allow you to add any kind of object(string,int).

---

Also `List<x>` cannot be assinged(`=`) to `List<y>` or vice versa if x can be converted to y or y can be converted to x..They both should be x or y thus providing type safety

So,you wont be able to **assign**(`=`) `List<String>` to `List<Object>` or vice versa..

Answer (score 1):

Generics are used to detect runtime exceptions at compile-time itself.

Assume that you created a `List` to store `Strings` and passed it to a method.. `enhanceList(List)`.. and after the execution, you will iterate through the list and get all strings

**before genercis**, it could have been possible that `enhanceList(List)` method will add *other type* of objects into the list creating possible `ClassCastException`

```
void someMethod() {
   List listOfStrings = new List();
   enhanceList(listOfStrings);

   for(Iterator i : listOfStrings.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        String s = (String) i.next(); //RuntimeException here
   }
}

void enhanceList(List l) {
    l.add(new Integer(1)); //error code
}
```

**with generics**, you can very well **"bind"** the type of objects the list contains

```
void someMethod() {
   List<String> listOfStrings = new List<String>();
   enhanceList(listOfStrings);

   for(String s : listOfStrings) {
       //no error here
   }
}

void enhanceList(List<String> l) {
    l.add(new Integer(1)); //compile-time error
}
```

However, generics should be used with caution, `List<Object>` doesn't help much with binding types because, it can hold any objects (since Object is super class of all the java classes). I recommend to create List of Specific type always.